# Opening a file from the default file browser on mobile device. No matter the browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, gmail, google-hangouts

I have a web app that prompts the user to upload a file with some standard html:

However, if the user opens the link from the mini-chrome that opens links from hangouts/gmail. The file browser that is used is different from the file browser used by navigating to the page with chrome.

My question is:
Is there a way to set default file browser on the web?

I understand you can set the default application to open links in the gmail app, this is irrelevant as the user will click the link from an email and it doesn't make sense to tell them to copy the link into chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the html is:   <input id="myFile" type="file"/>

Comment: _"My question is: Is there a way to set default file browser on the web?"_ You can create a custom HTML element which extends `<input type="file">` element, or apply CSS to `<label>` element associated with `<input type="file">` element. What is the purpose for setting a "default file browser"?